# Question about proof for law of total probability

Tags: probability

I'm currently studying statistics from a textbook and came across this proof for the law of total probability:

$$ Proof: Define\; C_j=BA_j, where \; C_1, C_2,... are\; disjoint\; and\; B=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} C_j. \;\\ Then, P(B) = \sum\limits_{j}P(C_j)= \sum\limits_{j}BA_j=\sum\limits_{j}P(B|A_j)P(A_j) \\
from \; conditional probability.$$

My question is: Regarding the first line, if $C_j=BA_j$, how is it that $C_1, C_2,...$ is disjoint? Wouldn't the intersection of $C_1, C_2, ...$ contain the event $B$ and is therefore not the empty set? Also, wouldn't $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k} C_j$ contain $A_k$ as well?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the events $A_j$ are disjoint, and my guess is that $\cup_{j=1}^k A_j = S$. Then the $C_j=BA_j$ are disjoint since $C_j\cap C_l=(B\cap A_j)\cap(B\cap A_l)=B\cap A_j\cap A_l=B\cap \emptyset=\emptyset.$ Then you can write $$B=B\cap S=B\cap(\cup_{j=1}^kA_j)=\cup_{j=1}^k BA_j=\cup_{j=1}^k C_j.$$

It's not clear at all if $B=\cup_{j=1}^k C_j$ would contain $A_k$.